# Dependency Injection and Interception in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-core

I am using Unity IOC in my current .NET 4.x class library application. The application uses both DI and Interception. I recently converted the application to .NET 5.0 so that I can target other OS like Linux as well. Unity still works but I am wondering if there are better solutions in .NET 5.0? I have heard that DI is first class citizen in .NET core but could not find any interception examples. I am not looking for ASP.NET core examples as my application is not web based. Wondering what my fellow members are using? Any advice?

Comment: I am still looking for an answer. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

.Net 5.0 comes with its own dependency injection, doesn't need third party assemblies for that,

```
using IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

 static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
                    services.AddTransient<ITransientOperation, DefaultOperation>()
                            .AddScoped<IScopedOperation, DefaultOperation>()
                            .AddSingleton<ISingletonOperation, DefaultOperation>()
                            .AddTransient<OperationLogger>());
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you let me know how to address cross cutting concerns like interception in .NET 5.0?

Comment: Suppose ClassA, ClassB and ClassC are in different libraries. ClassA depends on ClassB and ClassB depends on ClassC. How to I configure DI? Assume that developer of ClassA does not know about all dependencies of ClassB. How to correctly wire entire dependency chain?